# Automorphism group of the Leech lattice

Tags: group-theory, integer-lattices

I have seen that the automorphism group of the Leech lattice is the Conway group $\ Co_0$, which is a finite group.
But for example the lattice $\mathbb Z^n$ has an infinite automorhism group. Can anyone explain me, what is the difference between these two lattices, that results in the (in)finiteness of their respective automorphism  groups?

Comment: Here we want automorphisms $\Lambda = A \mathbb{Z}^n \mapsto AB \mathbb{Z}^n$ (for some $B \in SL_n(\mathbb{Z})$) preserving $\| \lambda \|^2= \| A v \|^2= v^T A^T A v$ ie. preserving the Gram matrix $A^T A \mapsto B^T A^T A B$. How to compute it ? We can take a basis of $\Lambda$ and send each basis element to an other element of $\Lambda$ of same $\|.\|^2$ (finite many) and test if it generates an isometry (so the isometry-automorphism group is always finite for any lattice)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are confusing isometries of a lattice, and isometries fixing
the identity. Each lattice in $\Bbb R^n$, considered as a point set, has infinitely
many isometries, since each translation by a lattice vector is
an isometry.

What is more interesting is studying the isometries that fix the origin.
They form a finite group, always non-trivial, as the map $x\mapsto-x$
is a (central) isometry. The first Conway group is obtained by taking
the group of Leech lattice isometries fixing $0$, and factoring out the two-element group generated by $x\mapsto-x$.

In $\Bbb Z^n$ the group of isometries fixing $0$ has $2^nn!$ elements,
and are the monomial matrices with nonzero entries either $1$ or $-1$.

Answer (score 6):

I may be wrong, but I suspect that here we consider automorphisms of a lattice *as subsets of a Euclidean space*, and we thus assume an automorphism to also be an *isometry*. Unless I'm wrong you were thinking about automorphisms of abelian groups. But, as abelian groups the Leetch lattice and $\Bbb{Z}^{24}$ are isomorphic. They differ only in their metric properties. In my opinion this strongly points at the groups of isometries being relevant here. To get finite groups we also assume that the origin is a fixed point.

In that interpretation an automorphism of $\Bbb{Z}^n$ is fully determined by its action on the short length 1 vectors. Therefore the automorphisms of $\Bbb{Z}^n$  form the group $C_2\wr S_n$ of signed permutations (of coordinates).